# How to prevent white spaces between paragraph and large images in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I want to write continuous paragraphs independent of images in between.

[image]What I am trying to do is to skip the white spaces between paragraphs and larges images, which do not fit in the rest of the page.

Please see the screenshot.

Comment: have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Word-Layout-Options-to-move-pictures-becff26a-d1b9-4b9d-80f8-7e214557ca9f.

Comment: Thanks Máté. The suggested page doesn't cover my need.

Comment: I think you need to set the images to floating - one of the text flow types for images will do what you need - experiment.

Comment: What you've tried? setting position "with text wrapping" (instead of "in line with text") should work as expected.

Comment: The problem is, a part of anchored paragraph remains in the image page. I want the image page completely for the image and its caption.

Comment: I don't think there would be an option for that, you can do two workarounds: 1. make the picture "in line with text" and put a page break immediately after it. 2. put the picture on an invisible (white) shape which fills the page.