# Insert a page break for a picture without leaving a blank space in microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having trouble finding the proper kind of break to do what I want.

I'll try to explain what I wish I had and what I'm able to obtain.

I wish I had that:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nisl
>   dui, tincidunt at tincidunt sed, auctor et orci. Vivamus eros leo,
>   tempus nec mi sed, molestie bibendum augue. Nulla tempor rhoncus est a
>   consectetur. Ut eu posuere lacus. Vestibulum iaculis mauris ligula, eu
>   auctor lectus mollis in. In sodales consectetur ex, eget tempus arcu
>   lacinia ut. Aenean consectetur neque mauris, sit amet malesuada sem
>   varius non. Donec ac vulputate massa. Nullam ultrices et nisl rhoncus
>   tincidunt. **(see picture 1)** Integer sit amet sem sollicitudin,
>   consectetur leo posuere, aliquam est. Aenean interdum est dictum arcu
>   blandit, in ultrices ex maximus. Fusce nec dolor at sapien cursus
>
> ---- (end of page because it's normally filled)
>
> Picture 1
>
> ---- (end of page)
>
> tincidunt facilisis sit amet arcu. Vivamus id ipsum vel urna luctus
>   ultrices. Phasellus lorem leo, iaculis at finibus at, viverra vehicula
>   urna. Cras pulvinar et tellus ac luctus. Integer id aliquet felis. In
>   hac habitasse platea dictumst.

In other words, I want the text to go on as it would normally and when the page is filled to jump to the page with the picture and then go back to the text, as if the page with the picture wasn't inserted, without breaking the paragraph.

For now what I have is :

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nisl
>   dui, tincidunt at tincidunt sed, auctor et orci. Vivamus eros leo,
>   tempus nec mi sed, molestie bibendum augue. Nulla tempor rhoncus est a
>   consectetur. Ut eu posuere lacus. Vestibulum iaculis mauris ligula, eu
>   auctor lectus mollis in. In sodales consectetur ex, eget tempus arcu
>   lacinia ut. Aenean consectetur neque mauris, sit amet malesuada sem
>   varius non. Donec ac vulputate massa. Nullam ultrices et nisl rhoncus
>   tincidunt. **(see picture 1)**
>
> [Manual page break]+[blank space I wish I could get rid of]
>
> --- end of page
>
> Picture 1
>
> [manual page break]
>   --- end of page
>
> Integer sit amet sem sollicitudin, consectetur leo posuere, aliquam
>   est. Aenean interdum est dictum arcu blandit, in ultrices ex maximus.
>   Fusce nec dolor at sapien cursus tincidunt facilisis sit amet arcu.
>   Vivamus id ipsum vel urna luctus ultrices. Phasellus lorem leo,
>   iaculis at finibus at, viverra vehicula urna. Cras pulvinar et tellus
>   ac luctus. Integer id aliquet felis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst

Does someone has any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: It sounds as though you're asking basically the same thing as these two very recent questions: [MS Word - make page (or its content) static](https://superuser.com/questions/1200542/ms-word-make-page-or-its-content-static) and [How to prevent white spaces between paragraph and large images in Word](https://superuser.com/questions/1198246/how-to-prevent-white-spaces-between-paragraph-and-large-images-in-word).

Comment: As cnread notes, there are three virtually identical questions.  Despite that, I still don't know exactly what objective you want to achieve, and in what way your attempts fail to achieve it.  Have you tried just inserting the picture without page breaks?  If you make the picture exactly full page size, I would think Word would force it to a page and adjust the text around it.

Comment: It's indeed the very same question, but it hasn't pop when I searched for it (and it wasn't suggested as similar questions when I submitted it) but thank you anyway.

Comment: You are saying the blank space appears AFTER the page break BUT on the same page? You are not talking any sense. How do you even manage to see it? Not mention, in what way does it bother you?

Comment: @FleetCommand This actually does make sense.  In the OP's case, he wants the text to completely fill the first page and have the ability to add or remove from the text without moving the image on the next page. He's using a manual page break to do this, but as soon as you add text to the first page, that manual page break moves to the next page (moving the image 1 page down and creating a new page that's almost entirely blank). If you remove text from the first page, the manual break moves *up* creating blank space at the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

*(I tried to flag this question as a duplicate of the [question](https://superuser.com/q/1200542/213131) where I originally posted, but it wasn't possible to do so, so I'm reposting the answer here.)*

> I want the text to go on as it would normally and when the page is filled to jump to the page with the picture and then go back to the text, as if the page with the picture wasn't inserted

Unfortunately, this simply cannot be done. Word has a lot of options for controlling how and where an image is anchored, but when you do not want the image to hide text behind it (using the *In Front of Text* wrap option), **all of the anchors move when text on the prior page is moved to the image's page.**

Here are some of the strategies I've tried over the years to 
(unsuccessfully) solve this problem:

1. **Anchor the image in the page header.**  This works great if you want the image to be locked to the first page of a document because you can use the *Different first page* header option.  However, it's pointless because nobody is trying to add text before the first page.
2. **Anchor the image with absolute placement on the page**. This ensures the image never moves on the page on which it is placed, but if enough text is added before the page such that it intrudes upon the page in question, the entire image simply moves to the *next* page.
3. **Employ a Next Page Section Break.** It's at this point we realize we're desperate and out of options.  With a Section Break you can apply different page settings for a particular page and ensure text in the prior section cannot intrude on the new section, but again, when text in the prior section is moved down into the page with the image, Word simply moves the image (and the section's start point) to the next page.

Word is a good document editor, but it's not meant for desktop publishing.  Programs like Microsoft Publisher or Adobe PageMaker are better suited to requirements such as this one and include features that handle these tasks much better than Word.

Answer (score 0):

As you may (or may not) have figured out, you can create a page break by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This will ensure that when you add text on the current page, the page break moves and other text does not move too.

But by default, word shows the layout when you print out your content, which means that even if a page break exists, you still see the empty space below a page break until the end of the document is reached.

If you are designing your document to be printed, this is of course ideal, but your question is not about printing it out and you want to get rid of the empty space.

Luckily, there are a few methods to do so.

In the default view, you can simply move the mouse cursor to between two pages, and see how the cursor changes. If you click (or double click) at that spot, the empty spaces will disappear and the pages shrink. You can still clearly see the page breaks, but not a big massive empty block of white.

An alternative way is to change the view to webview. This will change the document to one large white area. Page breaks are still shown as dotted lines, but nothing more. To do this, click the 2nd or 3rd item on the bottom left corner of word. Next to the horizontal scroll bar.

*I am not in reach of word as I'm at home, so things might be slightly off. I'll correct any mistakes monday when I get back to work.*

Comment: Thank you but you're not answering what I asked for. You are telling me to switch to draft view.

The document is indeed meant to be printed and I'm aware of manual page breaks.

I could very well insert a manual page break, insert my picture and its caption and insert another manual page break (it's in fact, what I'm showing in my example 2), but it's not giving me the result that I want.

What I want is the page break to occur when the page is normally filled (without splitting the paragraph), have my page with the picture, and then have another page with the end of the paragraph.

Comment: @NicolasPP I'm sorry, but your question is not that clear. I tried to answer it to the best of my abilities to what I thought was your question, which apparently is not your question. Please edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: I wasn't meaning to be rude, I really was thanking you but telling you it wasn't what I was looking for. I'm sorry if I offended you.

Comment: You haven't offended me, but it is hard to help you because I (and others) have no idea what you actually mean. If you edit your question and reword it, we may be able to give you an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **Top and bottom** wrapping style. Set the vertical position to **Alignment *Top* relative to *Margin***.

Drag the anchor to the appropriate spot. You'll have to play around with this, as I haven't much practice myself. I suspect that if you put it one page of text (or two pieces that add up to one page) later than your mention, it will always show up on the page after the mention.

Comment: Just realized that you have a picture that takes up a whole page. Hmm. Might still work. Try it.

Comment: This won't work. As soon as the text on the proceeding page moves down enough to encroach upon the page with the image, the anchor will move down as well.